# Powershell Use Wildcards when matching arrays

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, wildcard

I've been banging my head against a wall for hours now and am looking for some help. To simplify my issue, I have two arrays, one which contains wildcards, and the other which makes use of those wildcards:

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")
```

I cannot get PowerShell to recognize that these match.

**My end goal is to have an output that tells me that purple.102 and orange.abc are not in $WildCardArray.**

Seems super simple! Some of the things I've tried:

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")
foreach($Item in $SpelledOutArray)
{
$item | where {$wildcardarray -contains $item}
}
```

I get BLUE!.txt as a result because it's my control with no wildcards. If I change that to -notcontains, I get all of the results returned except BLUE. I've tried contains, match, equals, like and all of their opposites, compare-object, and nothing works. I get no errors, I just do not get the expected results

I tried replacing "*" with [a-zA-Z] and other combinations, but it replaces it literally, and not as a wildcard. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.... PSVersion 5.1 Win 10

Does anybody know the logic behind WHY like/match/contains doesn't work, and what I can do make it work? It doesn't have to be pretty, it just needs to work

Comment: `-contains` looks for exact match, and I'm pretty sure it threats `*` as a character without any special meaning

Comment: `$WildCardArray | ForEach-Object {$Wildcard = $_ ; $SpelledOutArray | Where-Object {$_ -like $WildCard}}`

Comment: @beatcracker that gives the wrong output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> banging my head against a wall for hours [..] Seems super simple!

That's probably a hint that it's not super simple. You're trying to cross match two lists: *red to red, yellow, blue.... then Blue to red, yellow, blue... then Green to red, yellow, blue...*.  30 comparisons but you only have 5 loops happening.

You need more.

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")

# Loop once over the spelled out items
foreach($Item in $SpelledOutArray)
{
    # for each one, loop over the entire WildCard array and check for matches
    $WildCardMatches = foreach ($WildCard in $WildCardArray)
    { 
        if ($item -like $WildCard) {
            $Item
        }
    }

    # Now see if there were any wildcard matches for this SpelledOut Item or not
    if (-not $WildCardMatches)
    {
        $Item 
    }
}
```

and the inner loop over WildCardArray can become a filter, but you have to be filtering the array, not the individual item as your code does.

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")

foreach($Item in $SpelledOutArray)
{
   $WildCardMatches = $wildcardarray | Where { $item -like $_ }

   if (-not $WildCardMatches)
   {
       $Item 
   }
}
```

And I guess you could mash that down into an unclear double-where filter if you had to.

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")

$SpelledOutArray |Where {$item=$_; -not ($WildCardArray |Where {$item -like $_}) }
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Do you know, how does your solution hold up under large amounts of data? If for example, the $WildCardArray were to contain 1000 items and $SpelledOutArray upwards of 100k?

Comment: @Nick It would work, but probably slowly, it's O(N*M) runtime. You might be better off if you could combine all your wildcards into one regex e.g. `@("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc") -notmatch '^RED-.*\.htm|.*\.yellow|BLUE!\.txt|.*\.green|.*\.purple$'` does it for your example. But you said your example was simplified, so that might not be easy / possible for whatever you're really doing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Funny you should mention it; that's what I went with in my answer ;-)

Comment: Taking a list of file names/extensions from a website via invoke-webrequest, storing that in an array (WildCardArray), and then querying thousands of shares recursively (SpelledOutArray), possibly millions of files to see if any files match anything from the webrequest all in a foreach -parallel workflow... so when I said simplified I meant super simplified :(  As long as it works I'm not super worried about time.

Answer (score 4):

Your wildcard array is effectively a list of patterns to look for. You can turn this into a single regex and match against that:

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")

# Turn wildcards into regexes
# First escape all characters that might cause trouble in regexes (leaving out those we care about)
$escaped = $WildcardArray -replace '[ #$()+.[\\^{]','\$&' # list taken from Regex.Escape
# replace wildcards with their regex equivalents
$regexes = $escaped -replace '\*','.*' -replace '\?','.'
# combine them into one regex
$singleRegex = ($regexes | %{ '^' + $_ + '$' }) -join '|'

# match against that regex
$SpelledOutArray -notmatch $singleRegex
```

This has the potential to be faster than checking everything in a loop, although I didn't test. Also, extraordinarily-long regexes may cause trouble as well.

Comment: I've been messing around with this solution and have a question. It doesn't seem to take the "."'s literally, meaning that a wildcard of *.yellow will pull "123.greenyellow" . Is this a quirk of regex? I looked up the wildcards but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Nick: Sorry, my escaping replacement actually _removed_ all those characters instead of escaping them. I fixed that now.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for this pattern.
**TIP:** This is an easy pattern to wrap in a function for easier reuse. Feel free to comment here if you have a library or example implementation of 
`$ArrayToCheck -notmatch ToSingleRegex($ComparisonStringArray)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$WildCardArray = @("RED-*.htm", "*.yellow", "BLUE!.txt", "*.green", "*.purple")
$SpelledOutArray = @("RED-123.htm", "456.yellow", "BLUE!.txt",  "789.green", "purple.102", "orange.abc")

$WildCardArray | %{$str=$_; $SpelledOutArray | ? {$_ -like $str}  }
```

other solution, not short

```
$WildCardArray | 
   %{$current=$_; $SpelledOutArray | %{ [pscustomobject]@{wildcard=$current; value=$_ }}} | 
        where {$_.value -like $_.wildcard }
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output... "*My end goal is to have an output that tells me that purple.102 and orange.abc are not in $WildCardArray.*" but your code outputs `RED-*.htm *.yellow BLUE!.txt *.green`