# Can I use splatting within a Where-Object using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What I want to find out if I can do, is splatting in a `Where-Object` clause or something similar. I know you can do this with parameters already.

I am trying to filter out multiple values from one property using `-notlike`.

I have looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1 but nothing is mentioned in here.

An example of what I'm currently trying to do:

```
$allUsers | Where-Object {($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike "Health*") -and ($_.UserPrincipalName -notlike "admin*")}
```

I am trying to do it this way as there are lots of accounts I want to exclude that contain the the word "admin" in their UPN. Unfortunately there is a long list of what I need to exclude, as I am running through a cleanup process.

I have been suggested to use an array of exclusions and then try using `-notcontains` or `-notin` but this has not worked for me, I'm assuming because I need it to be wildcard friendly.

Comment: Try using ($_.Property1 -notin $listofexclusions) instead of multiple -notlikes?

Comment: omg - I feel like a fool.

Comment: I seem to recall that PS can be finicky about this, you might find that ($listofexclusions -notcontains $_.property1) works if you have problems.

Comment: Unfortunately neither worked - I will add these attempts above

Comment: -Contains/-in/-notcontains/-notin are not substring/matching operators.  They are list containment operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to build a dynamic filter by just comma-separating your exclusion strings, which effectively creates an array of strings (`$Exclusions`).

```
$Exclusions = 'Health*','admin*'
$FilterArray = $Exclusions | Foreach-Object {
    "UserPrincipalName -notlike '$_'"
}
$Filter = @{'Filter' = "{0}" -f ($FilterArray -join " -and ")}

Get-ADUser @Filter
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a lot easier to use the regex `-notmatch` operator:

```
# create a regular expression string by combining the keywords with the OR '|' character
$exclude = ('test','admin','health' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
# get all users except the users that have any of the keywords in their UserPrincipalName
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName -notmatch $exclude }
```

Answer (score 0):

-notin works fine for me, maybe supply a bit more of your data in your question to see what you;re trying to filter out? Is it the wildcards causing an issue?

```
$listofexclusions = @("userid1","userid2")


Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -notin $listofexclusions } | Select Name,SamAccountName | ft
```

Edit:

If you need wildcards, there are some previous threads about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107211/powershell-use-wildcards-when-matching-arrays)

Comment: I'll edit my original post to show more info on what I'm doing. I was using `*` as a wildcard character, as there are lots of objects I want to exclude with "test" in them for example

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like `Get-ADUser` you can do what other answers have suggested and let the cmdlet filter the results for you using its built in functionality.

However, if you just want to apply a bunch of `-like` operations to a collection of objects you can write your own `Test-LikeAny` function as follows:

```bsh
function Test-LikeAny
{
    param( [string] $value, [string[]] $patterns )
    foreach( $pattern in $patterns )
    {
        if( $value -like $pattern )
        {
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```bsh
$values = @(
    (new-object pscustomobject @{ "Property1" = "...value1..." }),
    (new-object pscustomobject @{ "Property1" = "...value2..." }),
    (new-object pscustomobject @{ "Property1" = "...value3..." })
)

$patterns = @( "*value1*", "*value2*" )

$values | Where-Object { -not (Test-LikeAny $_.Property1 $patterns) }
```

which gives:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Property1                      ...value3...
```